# How do i find max and min of an nested ArrayList?

Tags: java

Let's say i have N ArrayLists and inside them, there are M other ArrayLists, so i'm trying to find the min and max of each of these M ArrayLists, what's the best way to do that?

```
    ArrayList<String> myname = new ArrayList<String>(n);
    ArrayList<Integer> myscore = new ArrayList<Integer>(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                              
        System.out.println("enter name of contestant");
        myname.add(input.next());
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {                         
            System.out.println("enter score");
            myscore.add(input.nextInt());
        }
```

Comment: Keep track of both on insert. If you cannot do that, you'll have to traverse them.

Comment: when you say *min and max* , do you mean the **size** of the List, or its actual contents ?

Comment: @Shashwat Lists contain integers, i mean the min and max integers

Comment: @ChanceTheFapper is the list sorted ? If not, the only way I can think of  is to traverse the list(or use streams)

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: You can use [Collections.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) on the "innermost" ArrayLists. Accordingly `Collections.min`

Comment: @Abhijith i have only created the loops and Lists. I can find the min and max but it finds the min and max values of all Lists, while i want min and max of each List.

Comment: @ChanceTheFapper, how many scores each contestant has ?

Comment: @Andro the user has to choose that. It can be any number.

Comment: @ChanceTheFapper, your question doesn't match your needs!!! please clarify your question. See my answer it could helps, otherwise, you need to update your question. According to your code, each contestant  should has one number (which is user defined), so you can find the max and min to know who is win. If I'm misunderstood, please clearly your question by steps. What the ' n ArrayLists' refers to? and also the 'm ArraLists'

Comment: If each contestant should has more than one score, then tell us, because that would need more code to fit your bill

Comment: @Andro There are N(user defined) contestants(first loop). Each contestant can have an M(user defined) number of Scores(which are also user defined). So the user has to chose how many contestants there are, how many scores they have (they all have the same number of scores) and then what scores does each of them have. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Andro yes, each contestant can have more than one score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not that much explanatory. Lets say that you want to add the names of some student and you also want to save the corresponding marks obtained by each student. So you will need three ArrayList reference variable. First one is for storing the names, second one is for storing the marks obtained by the student, and the third one is for storing the ArrayList of marks obtained by a single student. Here goes the code

```
package exmaple;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Finder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = userInput.nextInt();
        int m = userInput.nextInt();


        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(n);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers;

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> holderOfMarksArayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();


        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name of contentant.");
            String name = userInput.next();
            names.add(name);
            numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(m);
            for(int j = 0; j<m; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter score.");
                numbers.add(userInput.nextInt());
            }
            holderOfMarksArayList.add(numbers);
        }

        int counter = 0;
        for(String name : names) {
            numbers = holderOfMarksArayList.get(counter);
            Collections.sort(numbers);
            int maxScore = numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);
            int minScore = numbers.get(0);
            System.out.println(name +",  Max Score = " + maxScore + " Min Score = " + minScore);
            counter++;
        }
        userInput.close();

    }

}
```

If you try with the following input

AAA = 20, 80, 10

XXX = 66, 98, 96

YYY = 65, 12, 76

You will get the following output

AAA,  Max Score = 80 Min Score = 10

XXX,  Max Score = 98 Min Score = 66

YYY,  Max Score = 76 Min Score = 12

Comment: One more thing, What if i want a winner, and the winner is the guy with the biggest sum of elements.(ex: AAA= 110) How would i compare their sums?

Comment: If you want to find out the winner you should sum the marks obtained by each winner and compare it with a temp variable. if the sum is greater then the temp then assign the sum to the temp. the last value assigned in the temp will be highest mark obtained.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) class:

```
IntSummaryStatistics istats = IntStream.of(1,22,33,44,55).
                collect(IntSummaryStatistics::new,  IntSummaryStatistics::accept,
                        IntSummaryStatistics::combine);
System.out.println("Max: "+istats.getMax()+", Min: "+istats.getMin());
// Max: 55, Min: 1
```

Comment: @Shashwat, sorry what do you mean. It is actually a `stream`, do you mean comparing to `Stream.max` and `Stream.min`?

Comment: I meant with `list.stream().max(Integer::compare)` where `list` is an `ArrayList` of Integers. I meant that do we have any benefit by using `IntSummaryStatistics` ?

Comment: @Shashwat, If you need to get maximum only, I think it is better to use `stream.max()` since `IntSummaryStatistics`  will compute count, min, max, sum, and average.

Comment: This works, but how can i customize it that it shows the min and max of each list instead of all of them?

Comment: @ChanceTheFapper can you please update your original question and show us your data structure? Basically you need to do `.stream().collect(..)` on each list.

Comment: I'm trying to get the largest and smallest values of the elements in list "myscore"
 How do i format this properly?


          `ArrayList<String> myname = new ArrayList<String>(n);
        ArrayList<Integer> myscore = new ArrayList<Integer>(m);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                            
            System.out.println("enter name of contestant");
            myname.add(input.next());
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {                         
                System.out.println("enter score");
                myscore.add(input.nextInt());
            }`

Comment: i added the code on the main question if you could take a look

Comment: @ChanceTheFapper just use `myscore.stream.collect()` is will give you the `max` and `min`

Comment: It gives the max and min of all arrays, not of each separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.max(arrayList)`. Just to illustrate how it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> n = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> m0 = new ArrayList<>(); 
ArrayList<Integer> m1 = new ArrayList<>(); 

m0.add(100);     
m0.add(200);
m0.add(300);
m0.add(400);
n.add(m0);

m1.add(10);
m1.add(20);
m1.add(30);
m1.add(40);
n.add(m1);


System.out.println(n);
System.out.println(Collections.max(n.get(0)));
System.out.println(Collections.min(n.get(0)));
System.out.println(Collections.max(n.get(1)));
System.out.println(Collections.min(n.get(1)));


}
```

**RUN**

```
[[100, 200, 300, 400], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
400
100
40
10
```

For your case, you can loop through your n arraylists to get the min and max of each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the winner you should sum the marks obtained by each winner and compare it with a temp variable. if the sum is greater then the temp then assign the sum to the temp. the last value assigned in the temp will be highest mark obtained. After the first for loop the code will be like that.

```
    String winnerName = "";
    int temp = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for(String name : names) {
        numbers = holderOfMarksArayList.get(counter);
        int sum = 0;
        for( int number : numbers ) {
            sum += number;
        }

        if( sum > temp ) {
            temp = sum;
            winnerName = name;
        }

        Collections.sort(numbers);
        int maxScore = numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);
        int minScore = numbers.get(0);
        System.out.println(name +",  Max Score = " + maxScore + " Min Score = " + minScore +" Sum " + sum);
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Winner " + winnerName + " Total "+ temp);
```

Comment: Aaaaamazing! <3